# tag_bind() not working with an overlapping canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am creating a teaching environment where the user has the ability to select from a drop down menu certain options such as a camera or whiteboard, these are added to the GUI as a new canvas with their own objects. These objects are binded using the tag_bind with the left click however on clicking, the function is not ran.

I have tried binding using tag_bind with the main canvas however as the object is created using it's own canvas therefore, it cannot find the object.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk() 

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth() - 15
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

canvas = Canvas(root, width = screen_width, height = screen_height) 
canvas.pack() 

def add_item(event, remove):#this is the drop down menu
    dropbackground = canvas.create_rectangle(screen_width - 185, 70, screen_width - 55, 280, fill = "white")

    camera = canvas.create_text(screen_width - 120,85, text = "Camera", font = ("Segoe UI", 9))
    canvas.tag_bind(camera, "<Button-1>", lambda x: camera_func(x, False))
    line1 = canvas.create_line(screen_width - 170, 100, screen_width - 70, 100)

def camera_func(event):
   cam_canvas = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500, bg = "red")
   cam_canvas_object = canvas.create_window(500,500, window = cam_canvas)

   remove_button = PhotoImage(file = "cross.png")
   remove_button_object = cam_canvas.create_image(480,20, image = remove_button)
   remove_button.image = remove_button
   cam_canvas.tag_bind(remove_button_object, "<Button-1>", lambda x: camera_func(x, True))
```

I expect remove_button_object to be binded to right click and to run the camera_func with the given arguments however on clicking the remove_button_object the binding functions seems to not be working

Comment: Read the note about [Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method) maybe it explains the behavior.

Comment: @stovfl I read the note, how would I be able to go about placing a button that I can then bind onto this second canvas?

Comment: Unfortunatly can't run your code excample as it is no [mcve]